# Auto generate left and top css with absolute position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using these as examples:

> http://www.truedigital.co.uk
>   http://www.tinsels.fr
>   http://www.pinterest.com

There I saw a column of boxes for each post is well positioned neatly, I tried to do this using a variety of ways but each box column which I have made can not be exactly as on the website.

It looks like they make each field box making css left and top with automatic values and by using absolute positioning on each box. the possibility that using javascript / jquery, is there an example of a javascript like what they use to make the value of the css left and top auto like on the website?

Comment: jQuery can dynamically change CSS.  Just use the .attr[style] to add inline CSS or you can add/edit tag classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel.

You are looking for [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin.

Comment: Yeah, you right, few minutes ago i saw the script from truedigital.co.uk, and they are using Masonry. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what they are using: [jQuery Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the line of:

```
i = 0;
columnwidth = 300;
$('.box').each(function(){
    i++;
    if ( i > 4 ){
        i = 1;
    }
    $(this).addClass('column-' + i);
    $(this).css('left', (i-1) * columnwidth + 'px');

    columnheight = 0;
    $('column-' + i).each(function(){
        columnheight += $(this).css('height');
    }

    $(this).css('height', columnheight + 'px');
});
```

**LOOK HERE:**

this was rushed as I'm leaving the office, it probably won't work. This should give you an idea of what you will have to do to achieve your desired effect.

Comment: So this is the manual script without using Masonry or Isotop plugins, great, i will try it.. Thanks for the help